# What's the best way to load huge volume tables using Informatica?

Tags: oracle, bigdata, informatica

Currently, in our project, we are using Informatica for Data loading.

We have a requirement to load 100 tables (in future it will increase) and each has 100 Million records, and we need to perform delta operation on that. What might be the best way to perform this operation in an efficient way?

Comment: Why do you need to perform delta on a target table? Is it so you can do something about deletes? Do you have more than one source table? What do you mean by data dumping? Are you truncating the target table then reinserting all the records using bulk?

Comment: Yes, there might be some deletion or updates on the source tables and again yes, we have more than one source table....Data dumping I mentioned here referring Data load

Comment: "Big Data" is not a technology it is a marketing term for a whole bunch of different architectural styles.

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answerable, and is probably Off Topic anyway. But maybe the solution you want is Change Data Capture, which Oracle enables and Informatica supports through its Power Exchange feature. [Find out more](https://www.informatica.com/content/dam/informatica-com/global/amer/us/collateral/data-sheet/powerexchange-change-data-capture-option_data-sheet_1966.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible, try truncate and load. This way after each run you will have a full, fresh dump.

If you can't truncate the targets and need the delta, get some timestamp or counter that will allow to read modified rows only - like new and updated. Some "upddated date". This way you will limit the number of data being read. This will not let you do the deletes, though. So...

Create a separate flow for seeking deleted rows, that will not read the full row, but IDs only. This will still need to check all rows, but limited to just one column, so as a result it should be quite efficient. Use it to delete rows in target - or just to mark them as deleted.